# Kafka __consumer_offsets Topic's ISR and Replicas are not in sync along with the leader

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running in to an issue where the Kafka broker __consumer_offsets Topic's ISR and Replicas are not in sync along with the leader. We are seeing this issue when zookeeper nodes and broker nodes went down all of a sudden due to an issue and when they came back up( we restarted with unclean leader election to true) they were in an inconsistent state. Ran a reassign on the topic and that does not seem to work. So any consumer who has their offsets are unable to consume and have to recreate a new consumer group. We cant delete the topic and recreate as its complex to manage and coordinate it. Any recommendation as how to fix the replica and Leader as reassign is unable to fix it?

`Topic: __consumer_offsets    Partition: 19   Leader: 1040    Replicas: 1014,1006,1007    Isr: 1040,1025,1039`

Comment: 1) Do each of those broker IDs actual exist? 2) Do you know how to edit the znode in Zookeeper for that topic?

Comment: Yes the Broker nodes exist. And yes We are able to update the zk.

Comment: Maybe restarting broker 1040 is the safe approach. Otherwise, modifying `/brokers/topics/__consumer_offsets/partitions/19/state` in Zookeeper might work and make sure the ISR list there matches data at `/brokers/topics/__consumer_offsets`

Comment: We have the brokers restarted as well as we tried to update  another topic that is less critical and that did not help.We also tried to update /config/topics/__consumer_offsets as well . That did not help us.